# Node.js logging gets an issue when log files are rolling by OS.

Tags: node.js, linux, logging

I have Node.js application which is running under Linux system and uses log4js logging library. Log files are daily rolled by Linux rolling system. The question is the following: somebody know how force the log4js to recreate and use original log file when it's renamed somehow? 
Note, Log4js continue writes log into renamed file (seems, stream descriptor is kept).
Please note also that I don't want to use log4js DaylyRollingFileAppender because my log folder contains log files generated by various languages (Java, Python, JavaScript, Bash...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you use `logrotate`.

You can try using **'reload'** directive in logrotate config file. (see for details: http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)

It seems like that *log3js* can handle SIGHUP. (Issue: https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node/issues/343, Pull request: https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node/pull/403)

Secondary solution is configure it to use **'copytruncate'** directive, but it has trade-offs:
https://serverfault.com/questions/688658/rsyslog-with-logrotate-reload-rsyslog-vs-copytruncate

Comment: Thank you for answer. Ooh, 'copytruncate' is of course solution but it shock to performance because my application works under big load and logs are growing up to a few GB. So, Linux rolling is continued awhile and machine load reaches up to 8 - 10. Thus, my application is in fact hanged on this time. In short, I'm trying to avoid to use 'copytruncate'.

Comment: Seems like they now handle SIGHUP signal and you can try 'reload' directive. See this issue: https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node/issues/343. And pull request: https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node/pull/403. Probably it's not in npm yet. In this case you can (temporary) install directly from git.

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as 'Accepted'